# How to call internal javascript Class methods?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to OOP in JavaScript. Could someone please point out how I would go about calling an internal function from within a Class.

For example, from the below code how would I call the `hello` function from with the `myFunction`:

```
// app.js file
var Api = require('Api')
var api = new Api();

api.myFunction();

//server.js file

/**
 * API client.
 */
function Api() {
    this.my_var = 'my variable';
}

/**
 * My Function
 */
Api.prototype.myFunction = function() {
    // have tried this
    this.hello();

    // and this
    Api.hello();
}

/**
 * Hello
 */
Api.prototype.hello = function() {
    console.log('Hello!');
}

// expose the Api class
module.exports = Api;
```

Comment: what if you first set Api.prototype.hello and then Api.prototype.myFunction

Comment: yeah! try placing the hello() function definition above your myFunction() definition.

Comment: Your code works fine, this.hello should work. Can you show more code where it doesn't work? `var api = new Api; api.myFunction();` works.

Comment: @vs_lala Only functions defined with var follow order, functions declared after a line calling them will still work.

Comment: As @DaveChen mentioned, [this](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/fr5puL01/) is working..

Comment: @DaveChen I have updated the question. So when I call ```api.myFunction();``` The console tells me that ```undefined is not a function``` and reference the line that reads ```this.hello();```

Comment: @DaveChen oh yeah! I think he is calling the function wrong way, it will be Api.prototype.hello();

Comment: I must have something wrong...

Comment: Ok found a bug. Now it works

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = function() {

    this.my_var = 'my_variable';

    this.myFunction = function() {
        this.hello();
    };

    this.hello = function() {
        console.log('hello');
    };

    return this;
}
```